# Fourier expansion of Eisenstein Series

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, modular-forms, eisenstein-series, bessel-functions

I have been reading a bit about the Fourier expansion of Eisenstein series (weight 1/2). I came across the fact that the coefficients contain Modified Bessel functions.

Further reading I found articles discussing the zeros of these Bessel functions to behave similar to that of the zeta function (Re(s) = 1/2).

My question, is this or why isn't this a popular way to study Riemann's zeta function? Or have i misunderstood an obvious vital key element?

Comment: Can you explain this connection more clearly?

Answer (score 4):

The relationship has actually motivated several studies:

- [Eisenstein series and the Riemann zeta function](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/scanned/EisensteinRiemannZeta/fulltext.pdf) (1981)
- Moments of the Riemann zeta function and Eisenstein series [part I](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X03001811) and [part II](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X03001823) (2004)
- [The Riemann hypothesis for
  certain integrals of Eisenstein series](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412039) (2004)

Some of its limitations are discussed in an answer to this [MO question.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14083/modular-forms-and-the-riemann-hypothesis)

Comment: Your link to Zagier's paper is slightly mangled: it should have mpim-bonn rather than mpimbonn...

Comment: I've sen the first link, but not the last two. Thanks I'll check those out.